# xsltproc doesn't recognize XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xpath

I have this XSLT syltesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <!-- Default behavior: copy everything -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Do not copy: -->
  <xsl:template match="NodeLevel1[matches(NodeLevel2/@Param1, 'myRegex')]">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, I want to copy everything but certain nodes based on a regex expression. And I want to use the matches function of XSLT 2 to achieve this. But when I run the following command:

```
xsltproc.exe style.xsl input.xml > output.xml
```

I got this message looped on the standard output:

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function matches not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
xmlXPathCompiledEval: 1 object left on the stack
```

How to fix this please ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or the other options listed on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-2.0/info, xsltproc is an XSLT 1.0 processor.